# Localstack and python and docker-compose strange behaviour

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, localstack

I have created a docker-compose file for [localstack](https://github.com/localstack/localstack/blob/master/docker-compose.yml) and I'm using only services like `s3 and SQS`.  It works fine and I could create a dummy `SQS, S3` from localstack using AWS CLI command and can reach the localstack container from outside.  I have created SQS queue name called `mytestqueue`

Now, I have created this simple boto3, python script, and this python script is used as a new service to the existing local-stack docker-compose :

```
python3-boto3:
    image: python/boto3:latest
    container_name: boto3
    environment:
      - "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=dummyaccess"
      - "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=dummysecret"
      - "AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=eu-west-1"
      - "AWS_ENDPOINT=http://localstack:443"
    volumes:
      - "$PWD:/usr/src/app/"
    command: python /usr/src/app/boto3_python.py
```

Boto3Script boto3_python.py:

```
sqs_client = boto3.client("sqs",
                          region_name=os.environ.get('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
                          endpoint_url=os.environ.get('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
                          aws_access_key_id=os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
                          aws_secret_access_key=os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'))

response = sqs_client.get_queue_url(QueueName='mytestqueue')
print(response)
```

Now the strange problem is happening: maybe there is an explanation but still can't figure it out.

Now if I run the `docker-compose up` command I'm getting the error `The specified queue does not exist for this wsdl version.` that means my Queue is not reachable from the container `boto3` but now, if I get into this boto3 container and run this exact python script, then everything works fine, no URL issue.

So, can anyone tell me why in docker-compose this same script shows the URL can't be reachable while inside the container it works perfectly fine.

Comment: You'll need to wait for localstack to create SQS queues and S3 buckets before  python3-boto3 comes into action. You can use docker-compose's wait-for-it.sh feature.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue, by simply adding the `sleep` command in my python boto3 script.

If anyone has a similar issue, add the sleep command it will work. I'm not sure if there is any elegant solution exists but if anyone has please post here.